# Wind volume increasing on door rotation issue, how to fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a basic car model and a wind sound. The wind has been made so it gets louder as the car speeds up, but also louder as the door opens wider. It works all fine on the left door, but screws up on the right door. I think its something to do with the rotation of the right door, at first it will be at about 90º before moving, but then as the door opens, it goes past 360º and then back to 0º, where it continues rotating. This is what I think is messing it up, but I don't know. If that is the problem, could someone show me how to fix it, or if it isn't, then tell me what the problem actually is, and then how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
if(cameraIndex == 1){
        outsideCamera.enabled = false;
        driverCamera.enabled = true;
        passengerCamera.enabled = false;
        FPCamera.enabled = false;


        float driverVolume = 0.1f * (motor.speed / motor.topSpeed) + 0.1f;
        outsideCamera.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = 0f;
        driverCamera.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = driverVolume;
        passengerCamera.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = 0f;
        FPCamera.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = 0f;

        ambientSound.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = 0.5f;

        if(motor.ignitionIndex == 1){
            motor.engineSoundSource.volume = 0.5f;
            motor.hornSoundSource.volume = 0.8f;
        }


        if(leftDoor.clickCount == 1){
            driverCamera.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = driverVolume + ((leftDoor.transform.localEulerAngles.y) / 150) * ((motor.speed / motor.topSpeed) / 1.5f);
            if(motor.ignitionIndex == 1){
                motor.engineSoundSource.volume = 0.6f;
                motor.hornSoundSource.volume = 0.9f;
            }
        }

        //problem area below            

        if(rightDoor.clickCount == 1){
            driverCamera.GetComponent<AudioSource>().volume = driverVolume + ((((rightDoor.transform.localEulerAngles.y) - (210 + 150)) * -1) / 150) * (motor.speed / motor.topSpeed / 1.5f);
            if(motor.ignitionIndex == 1){
                motor.engineSoundSource.volume = 0.6f;
                motor.hornSoundSource.volume = 0.9f;
            }
        }

        activeCamera = driverCamera;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think that's your issue as well, because it will probably give a negative volume when you're just substracting 90.

I don't exactly know how to fix it, because I don't know how it goes trough the degrees as the door opens, but I'd recommend just tweaking your code. Try adding 90 or subtracting your angle from 90 instead of the other way around.

You subtracted 90 because at the other side it starts at 90 right? And then it's goes to 91, 92 all the way to 180, and that's then linked to the volume. Because that could mean you don't even need to subtract 90 at the other side, just inverse it or something. Maybe try this: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Inverse.html

Comment: I got it working now, I made two empties with the rotation all set at zero and with a little equation got the values to be the same as the left door.

Comment: Nevermind, still goes over 360. I've updated the code above, could you take a look at that?

Comment: Hmm, well, you know when the door will start to open. Because, as I understand it that's done by clicking. Is this all in the Update()? 
You could just save the starting value of the rotation of the door opening when the user clicks it. Globally. And then you keep checking the difference, and if the difference is over 90 degrees (or something like that, figure out for yourself what value this is), that's impossible and it has gone over the 360. So you just check for the real value of the door turn + 360. I hope I'm making sense, I could write some pseudo code if I don't. Hope this fixes it.

Comment: Ok, a few things. The door is done by clicking, it is all in the update, and when I saved the starting value of the rotation of the door it was just 0, 0, 0 as I have used an empty with all the values reset for simplicity. But as for checking the values I'm not sure if I fully understand...

Comment: Then I really don't understand your rotation, how does it get past 360 if the start rotation is 0?

Comment: Lol! I don't either! But I think whats happening is for just one frame its going below 0, i.e. 3º, 2º, 1º, 0º, 359º, 358º...and then after that one frame it snaps back to 0, but even though its one frame, you can still notice it really clearly with the audio. At least thats what I think is happening...

Comment: That's even weirder, can you maybe record the door rotating? in the scene with the rotation values on screen. I don't think I can help you otherwise

Comment: Sure thing, here is a short video, please just don't share the link, don't want too many people seeing the game just yet! (https://youtu.be/DkLh1eDt2S0)